# How to uniquely identify medias(images, videos) while sync across devices using cloud

Tags: android, ios, synchronization, cloud

Am creating an gallery **application(android & iOS)**, where I have to Sync **media albums(image, video)** across devices using **cloud(google drive, dropbox, flickr)**.

When synching medias, First i have to check whether the medias is in device or not, then only i have to download media. **How can i uniquely identify each and every media?**

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the type of cloud service you're using. With Dropbox/Google Drive, the filename would be the identifier, but if you're using any PaaS with a database to sync the data, each entry in the database would have its own object ID. While being unsure about the purpose of your app, you'd generally would want to use a cloud server and not Dropbox/Google Drive if this is a main part of your application.

Here's an example of how a cloud sync service could be structured:

You deployed a cloud server to [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) or [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com), which connects to a database like MongoDB or PostgreSQL. The database has a table for your users. Then there's a table for media item URLs, which are securely referenced to the owning user. The URLs point to a data bucket (e.g., Amazon S3). Your app sends requests to your cloud server, which gets the items for you from their storage.

Your app user signs up or logs in to either iOS or Android app, where his or her media items are imported and stored locally as well as in the cloud. Comparing timestamps of the stored items and making requests to the cloud server, you can determine if you should download newer versions of them.

Parse Server recently became open source, maybe that's a good place for you to start. Formerly known as parse.com and owned by Facebook, they also have some good example apps, [one of which](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic) is similar to your use case.